# Format text or set a mask for a cell of datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I wonder how can I create a mask or formatting system for a particular column in a datagridview where the user enters values ​​in this column, cash values....

My solution to this problem is not very functional because the user has to enter the value, and then the system adds value to the mask, only after the user leaves the cell...

if you have a way to edit the mask or capture the event when they type something in the cell, perhaps I can now create masks ...

Answer (score 0):

Part of your question is answered [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f9x2790s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). E.g. you can apply currency formatting on a column like this:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["UnitPrice"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
```

To actually interfere while the user is typing, you need to get the events for the editing control that is used on the cell. [This question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784701/datagridview-events) might get you started with that.

My own word of caution: the more you try to interfere with the DataGridView, the nastier it comes back to bite you :) A lot is possible, but sometimes it pays to rethink you original problem or come up with an alternative that doesn't involve tinkering around with the DataGridView too much.

Comment: btw, I tried to use that DefaultCellStyle, but, when the user tipe, nothing happens

Comment: Same for me. Looks like nothing happens when the user changes the value of a cell with a custom format.